# Сортировка по алфавиту и длине сразу

Tags: python, сортировка

**Исходные данные:** есть файл .txt, в нем записаны слова через строчку, например:

```
aaa\n
c\n
bb\n
aa\n
a\n
cc\n
bbb\n
b\n
ccc\n
```

**Цель:** сделать сортировку по алфавиту и длине строк.

**Вопрос:**
Пока что код есть такой, не знаю как правильно задать ключу сортировки, чтобы выполнялась сортировка так, как нужно, помогите, пожалуйста. Данный код выполняет сортировку только по длине строк..

```
open_file = open('testlist.txt', 'r').readlines()
save_file = open('testlist_sorted.txt', 'w')

for line in sorted(open_file, key=len):
    save_file.write(line)
```

Буду благодарен вашей помощью!
С уважением,
Иван.

Answer (score 2):

Просто убери ключ.

```
>>> t = ['a', 'cc', 'b', 'bbb', 'aaa', 'aa', 'c', 'ccc', 'bb']
>>> sorted(t)
['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'b', 'bb', 'bbb', 'c', 'cc', 'ccc']
```

Если тебе нужен какой-то другой результат, то опиши в вопросе что ты должен получить на выходе.